# Example of $S$-Noetherian rings

Tags: ring-theory, modules, examples-counterexamples, noetherian, integral-domain

I found a problem in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312907984_On_Right_S-Noetherian_Rings_and_S-Noetherian_Modules) on Example 1.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$ such
that $R$ is $S$-Noetherian but not Noetherian. (For example, one may take $R$ to be
a non-Noetherian integral domain with $S = R \backslash \{0\}$). In those paper said that such example can be found in [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243046167_S-Noetherian_rings).

But in another version of this paper, said that such example can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301636783_Modules_Satisfying_the_S-Noetherian_Property_and_S-ACCR) on Example 3.1. I've read this example. Why those example is $S$-Noetherian but not Noetherian?
 How to prove that non-Noetherian integral domain with $S = R \backslash \{0\}$ is $S$-Noetherian but not Noetherian ? How to find another example?